# Emacs to vim causes two tab characters

Tags: python, vim, emacs, tabs

I'm editing a file that was initially written in emacs and that I am now working on in vim. I've been running into an odd problem when switching from one to the other:

At *some* places in the code, seemingly randomly, there are tabs in the emacs code that are equivalent to two tabs (both visually in emacs and in python). However, in vim these tab characters show up as only a single tab.

When I :set list, an example few lines will show up as:

```
    for i in range(total_pairs):$
^Iwhile 1:$
^I    rint = random.randint(0,total_pairs-1)$
^I    if(trialData[rint].cueDir == FORWARD)$
^I^ItrialData[rint].cueDir=BACKWARD$
^I^Ibreak$
```

While it should appear as:

```
    for i in range(total_pairs):$
        while 1:$
            rint = random.randint(0,total_pairs-1)$
            if(trialData[rint].cueDir == FORWARD):$
                trialData[rint].cueDir = BACKWARD$
                break$
```

The code still runs either way, but it's fairly annoying to read.

When I run :retab, it replaces each ^I with one tab, instead of the two tabs that it should. What can I do to replace each ^I character with two tabs instead of one. Also, why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy, (and recommended), answer is replace each tab with 4 spaces and set **both** emacs and vim to use 4 spaces when tab is pressed.

Comment: Got it. I don't know why I thought it wasn't working before, but your suggestion worked. I issued the command `:%s/\t/~~~~~~~~/g` (each ~ is equal to one space. Couldn't figure out how to format it properly). I had to replace each \t with eight spaces, not four. Still not sure why it was happening though.

Comment: Some editors do some funny things with tabs - this is one reason why spaces is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run :retab, it replaces each ^I with one tab, instead of the two tabs that it should.

`:retab` replaces each tab character (i.e. `^I`) with `tabstop` spaces. In your case, `tabstop` is evidently set to 4, so Vim replaces each `^I` in the file with 4 spaces. If you expect `:retab` to replace each `^I` with 8 spaces, use `set tabstop=8` before `:retab`.

To address the actual problem, do not use mixed indentation in Python; set up both Emacs and Vim to use spaces for tabs.

See `:h expandtab`, `:h tabstop`, `:h softtabstop`, and `:h shiftwidth` for more information.

Comment: BTW, to “do not use mixed indentation” statement: using mixed indentation is a `TabError` in python 3. And it was never PEP8-compliant.